What do these footnotes mean?
BH
Hi, what do these footnotes mean? Are they related to the text?


The english notes are translation of the text

They look like variant spellings/wordings from various manuscripts of the work

What DoubleAA says is correct. If you look in the opening pages of the volume that you have, it will likely explain the various editions and manuscripts that the editor used to assemble their printed text of Sefer Ginat Egoz (assuming written by Rabbi Yosef Gikatilla, the student of Rabbi Avraham Abulafia).
